# Graph discovery and cycle detection

Tags: algorithm, graph, cycle, graph-algorithm

Consider the graph below

[image: Graph Structure]

Assume that the program starts executing at time t = 0 and has initially discovered the node A. At time t = 0 no other nodes are discovered. At time t = 4 the program has discovered all the nodes in the graph above and is back at its starting state thus completing  a cycle.

My question is as follows:

- Assuming that no prior information is available about the graph what is the best possible way to do this for a graph with a large number of nodes (n > 1000) and many cycles  (not necessarily as simple and direct as above.) **I do not want to detect cycles after discovering the whole graph.**

Comment: Is the graph guaranteed to be connected at any time? For a newly discovered edge, do you need to detect whether it belongs to a cycle, find some cycle it belongs to, or find all cycles it belongs to?

Comment: @user3290797 yes it is guaranteed to be connected.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are describing is pretty much a [**DFS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) - choose one branch - and develop it as much as you can.

Another common graph discovery algorithm is [**BFS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) - "discover" all nodes at distance 0 from the source, then at distance 1, .... until all graph is discovered.

Note that a variation of DFS, that holds a dynamic 'visited' set (and allows to rediscover nodes that are already discovered, but not in the current branch) can be used for cycles detection (assuming you want all cycles), but may take a long time to run - because there could be exponential number of cycles in the graph

Comment: Node detection followed by cycle detection. I want a method where these two detections work sequentially as in if a new node is discovered then cycle detection checks whether the newly discovered/encountered node represent a cycle. I do not want to detect cycles after discovering the whole graph. –  Synex 37 secs ago

Comment: @Synex I am not following. Do you want to detect ALL the cycles? if there is any cycle? If you want all cycles - DFS can do it, read the last paragraph of the answer, it describes it.

Comment: yes. I want to detect all cycles. However the problem as I see is that a node are discovered in a sequence as well as links. If node A is identified it does not necessarily mean that all edges originating from A is known. May be at t = 70 another edge would be discovered. This is dynamic graph with same node being encountered repeatedly after the initial discovery. So A can be a start and the end of a large number of cycles.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to give you solution , you should try yourself ,
but here is something which will get you going :
I am using [Depth First Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)  here .

```
initially all nodes grey

for each node
    mark it as white
    dfs(grey child)
    mark node black

dfs(node)
if(child node white) 
  CYCLE detected
else ...normal routine
```

If you still are not able to understand , i will elaborate .